# EF4 Oracle Identity Insert

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-4, identity-column, entity-framework-ctp5, devart

Does anyone know if its possible to call an oracle's sequence.NextVal from ef4 without using StoredProcedure? I have an Oracle db from a client which I cannot modify, so stroedproc are not an option for me. I use ef4 ctp5.

Thank!

Comment: Are you using DevArt or Oracle's EF provider?

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can execute an SQL command:

```
  OracleParameter param = new OracleParameter("p", OracleDbType.Integer, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output);
  oContext.Database.SqlCommand("begin SELECT sequence_name.nextval into :p FROM dual; end;", param);
  int i = (int)param.Value;
```

I have tested this code using dotConnect for Oracle 6.0.86, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with ef4 but can you execute regular queries like this?

```
SELECT sequence_name.nextval
FROM dual;
```